# pod repo lint error: [!] An unexpected version directory `<a dir>` was encountered for the `<Parent Dir>` Pod in the `<Parent Dir>` repository

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I am tryin to lint my pod spec and getting the following error.

`[!] An unexpected version directory 'ios' was encountered for the 'Classes' Pod in the 'Classes' repository.`

My source folders are set as follows:

Classes
 - ios
 - osx

Podspec has source files as:

```
s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*.*'
```

Any ideas what is causing this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK I was having a bad day. Should have been using:

> pod spec lint .

Comment: I've looked at this question and answer a dozen times, and every time your `OK I was having a bad day.` makes me laugh as I type `pod spec lint .` in my console.